Why does `display: unset` on a div make it `inline`?
According to MDN:

The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if the property naturally inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. In other words, it behaves like the inherit keyword in the first case, when the property is an inherited property, and like the initial keyword in the second case, when the property is a non-inherited property.

So, since display is NOT an inherited value, I'm expecting the display: unset to make a div be block which is its "initial value".
But doing a quick test it gives me the value of inline:


let output = document.querySelector('#output');
let box = document.querySelector('#box');
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let computedDisplay = box.computedStyleMap().get('display').value;
  output.innerText = computedDisplay;
});
#box {
  display: unset;
}
<div>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <div id="box">box</div>
  <button id="btn">Get</button>
</div>



What am I understanding wrong here?

The documentation you linked to clearly says Initial: inline. Why do you think it should be block?

Damn, I just noticed that but isn't a div a block level by default?

display: block is a rule of the user agent style sheet, not an initial value

Thanks, I hate this. Found the reference for it. Will post an answer.

Fun fact: Tags like <script> and <style> also have the initial value of display: inline. If you assign * { display: unset } then you will be able to see them in the document as well.

Thanks to @Barmar and @DustInComp the default display is inline but browsers set it to block for divs. Here's the Chrome reference.
More links:

w3 - default-style-sheet
whatwg - flow-content

There is also CSS revert:

The revert CSS keyword reverts the cascaded value of the property from its current value to the value the property would have had if no changes had been made by the current style origin to the current element. Thus, it resets the property either to user agent set value, to user set value, to its inherited value (if it is inheritable), or to initial value. It can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand property all.


Thinking "for a div" may be the misleading bit. The display property's default value is inline, period. So it must be overridden by a default style sheet to confirm with expectations https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#default-style-sheet

This is some different level of s...

This is specified here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#flow-content-3
